# Zookeeper subnetwork based ACL

Tags: ip, apache-zookeeper, acl

From [zookeeper doc](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperProgrammers.html#sc_ZooKeeperAccessControl)

> **ip** uses the client host IP as an ACL ID identity. The ACL expression is of the form addr/bits where the most significant bits of addr are matched against the most significant bits of the client host IP.

However `setAcl /node1 ip:127.0.0.1/16:cdrwa` returns `Acl is not valid : /node1` (`setAcl /node1 ip:127.0.0.1:cdrwa` works fine)

Do I miss anything?

Checked with 3.4.8 and 3.4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, caused by [the bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1673) which was fixed in 3.5

Comment: A useful Answer! And is there any other way to implement this function in 3.4.*?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any. Bugfix is small and easy backportable if you don't mind bothering with your own artifact storage.